# Is innodb required/recommended for Spring Security?

Tags: mysql, grails, spring-security, innodb

I have a grails app that uses the Spring-Security-Core plugin, which integrates Spring Security 3 into my app. I belive that Spring/Hibernate will do some transactional operations under the hood. If that is the case, would it be better to use mysql's  innodb engine instead of the default MyIsam engine? or are the operations independent of the underlying database?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing particularly transactional about how the plugin works. It only reads - the primary database access will be loading a user and the user's assigned roles. You will want to use transactions when updating the user, assigning roles, etc. but that has nothing to do with security, it's just the right thing to do.

As the others said, there's very little reason to use MyISAM except in specialized use cases that are probably better suited for a NoSQL database. InnoDB is very fast and has excellent transaction support.

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB enforces referential integrity; MyISAM does not.

Looks like MyISAM does not support transactions/rollback:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

So if a transaction manager is required, better to go with InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think innodb engine will be wise choice. Main reason - durability and data integrity support. MyIsam more "fragile".  Only reason to use it now- huge insert activity - and this is not your case( i try to not go too deep in it- it more complex and don't connected with question).